# pyinstaller file too big to fit in memory

Tags: python, python-2.7, exe, pyinstaller

I'm trying to convert this simple script to .exe .

```
 #!/usr/bin/python

print "pyinstaller is nice!"
```

the command is :

```
pyinstaller toExe.py
```

output is :

```
6 INFO: wrote /tmp/toExe.spec
17 INFO: UPX is available.
26 INFO: Processing hook hook-os
73 INFO: Processing hook hook-time
74 INFO: Processing hook hook-cPickle
105 INFO: Processing hook hook-_sre
155 INFO: Processing hook hook-cStringIO
198 INFO: Processing hook hook-encodings
204 INFO: Processing hook hook-codecs
395 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with /tmp
396 INFO: checking Analysis
396 INFO: building because toExe.py changed
396 INFO: running Analysis out00-Analysis.toc
413 INFO: Analyzing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/loader/_pyi_bootstrap.py
418 INFO: Processing hook hook-os
427 INFO: Processing hook hook-site
434 INFO: Processing hook hook-encodings
478 INFO: Processing hook hook-time
479 INFO: Processing hook hook-cPickle
510 INFO: Processing hook hook-_sre
561 INFO: Processing hook hook-cStringIO
609 INFO: Processing hook hook-codecs
837 INFO: Processing hook hook-pydoc
893 INFO: Processing hook hook-email
918 INFO: Processing hook hook-httplib
936 INFO: Processing hook hook-email.message
967 INFO: Analyzing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py
984 INFO: Analyzing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_archive.py
1004 INFO: Analyzing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_carchive.py
1020 INFO: Analyzing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_os_path.py
1025 INFO: Analyzing toExe.py
1026 INFO: Hidden import 'codecs' has been found otherwise
1026 INFO: Hidden import 'encodings' has been found otherwise
1026 INFO: Looking for run-time hooks
objdump: section '.dynamic' mentioned in a -j option, but not found in any input file
1138 INFO: Using Python library /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
1138 INFO: Adding Python library to binary dependencies
1238 INFO: /tmp/build/toExe/out00-Analysis.toc no change!
1241 INFO: checking PYZ
1243 INFO: checking PKG
1243 INFO: building because toExe.py changed
1244 INFO: building PKG (CArchive) out00-PKG.pkg
objdump: section '.dynamic' mentioned in a -j option, but not found in any input file
1264 INFO: checking EXE
1264 INFO: rebuilding out00-EXE.toc because toExe missing
1264 INFO: building EXE from out00-EXE.toc
1269 INFO: Appending archive to EXE /tmp/build/toExe/toExe
1270 INFO: checking COLLECT
1270 INFO: building COLLECT out00-COLLECT.toc
```

I tested it in windows 7 and XP and always got the same message : file too big to fit in memory.
My python version is 2.7.3 on Kali linux.

Thanks.

Comment: Did yo try pyinstaller toexe.py -F

Comment: Yes , same result but .exe is bigger.

Comment: what is the size of the exe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Program too big to fit into memory" [means that the executable file's header is corrupt or the file has incorrect format](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/01/30/519388.aspx).

Are you, by any chance, trying to run a Linux executable in Windows?

(Windows executables start with "MZ", Linux ELF executables start with "⌂ELF")